# How can I convert plain text to HTML (preferably using Perl)?

Tags: html, perl

Is there a way to take a plain text file and convert it to a simple HTML?

A couple of 'sophisticated' stuff that will be great

- identify hyper-links.
- identify (tab delimited) tables.

**UPDATE**

I just found this [HTML::FromText](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aFromText). Checking to see if it meets my needs...

Comment: no more than 20 lines in perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Text::Markdown`](http://p3rl.org/Text::Markdown)

Stack Overflow already uses Markdown because it's the best mark-up language targeted to general text to HTML conversion. Named links are explained in the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: How do I add a table in Markdown? Also, do I have to read the entire file into a string and pass it at once or do it line by line?

Comment: Tables are not in the [Markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), but in the [MultiMarkdown syntax](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/users_guide/multimarkdown_syntax_guide/#tables).

Answer (score 3):

Try [HTML::TextToHTML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTextToHTML):

From the command line:

```
txt2html I<arguments>
```

From Scripts:

```
use HTML::TextToHTML;

# create a new object
my $conv = new HTML::TextToHTML();

# convert a file
$conv->txt2html(infile=>[$text_file],
                 outfile=>$html_file,
                 title=>"Wonderful Things",
                 mail=>1,
  ]);

# reset arguments
$conv->args(infile=>[], mail=>0);

# convert a string
$newstring = $conv->process_chunk($mystring)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. One thing I'm missing: how can I control the names hyperlinks are given? currently it just shows the full URL. I want all inks to be simply displayed as 'link' in the text. Can I do that? I read about the link dictionary but didn't really get it. I don't mind altering the text files somehow to do this explicitly.

Comment: almost forgot: +1. But I must admit I can't make the dictionaries work, so I;ll probably goo with MultiMarkdown.

Comment: I can't make link dictionaries work either. I think any markdown solution is probably the right one. In defense of my answer, you did ask for text->html, not marked-up text->html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lynx with -dump option to achieve that:

```
use File::Temp;

sub html2Txt {
    my $html = shift;
    my $html_file = File::Temp->new(SUFFIX => '.html');
    print $html_file $html;
    close $html_file;
    return scalar `lynx -dump $html_file 2> /dev/null`;
}

print html2Txt '<h1>Hi there!</h1> Testing <p>Testing</p>';
```

Comment: The question if for text 2 html, not html 2 text.